# Discrete spectrum ergodic system.

Tags: ergodic-theory

An ergodic measure preserving transformation T has discrete spectrum.
 How can I show that there is a sequence ${n_k}$ of integers such that 
$||{T^{n_k}f-f}||_2$  goes to zero?

Any hint or answer would be appreciated.

Comment: what is your definition of $f$?

Comment: f is just a L^2 function.